# ACID Problems in a Multithreaded Environment

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, innodb, acid

I have a multi-threaded java application which executes a lot of parallel CRUD operations on an MySQL Database. As read in MySQL manuals, InnoDB table structure should ensure, that the transactions are executed following the ACID priciples. But I still have problems, because sometimes, the Updates get lost. This is one of the example Stored Procedures that I use:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE *** (
    _*** INT,
    _*** INT,
    _*** INT,
    _*** INT
)
BEGIN
  START TRANSACTION;

    UPDATE `***` 
    SET  
      `***`.`***` = `***`.`***` + _***,  
      `***`.`***` = `***`.`***` + _*** + _***,  
      `***`.`***` = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL _*** SECOND)  
    WHERE `***`.`***` = _***;

  COMMIT;
END;
// 
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: bewate of the I in ACID. Isolation of transactions is a complex problem. Try to set the transaction level to serializable to avoid concurrent updates on the same row, or put some row locks.

Comment: @regilero: You should put that as an answer! Vilius: Also read this: http://www.mpopp.net/2005/12/tx-isolation-levels-3-repeatable-read-serializable/

Comment: I have read the article and some other articles about the transaction levels, but still it did not work for me ... I will reconsider the design of the Java application instead and update the MySQL Server to the 5.5 branch.

Answer (score 3):

The JDBC classes are not reentrant, so you have to synchronise use of object instances of connection, statement, etc. They cannot savely be used by multiple threads concurrently.

Use of a connection pool is a good way to streamline concurrent access to a database.

**Edit**

If you're sure that the threads never use the same connection, you could check

- can the pool be out of connections? how is that handled?
- could it be that 2 updates act on the same record where the first get overwritten?
- do you catch all exceptions and log them in your workers?

Comment: The sad thing is, that I am already using a Connection Pool (BoneCP) ... I also use a ThreadPoolExecutor to handle the different Threads that execute the SQL operations - the workqueue used for the ThreadPoolExecutor works in a FIFO way. I thought that these both technologies would ensure an errorless concurrent access to a database.

Comment: Thank's for the suggestions! I basically think that the second bullet point causes the problems ... That is why I believe that the error occurs at the MySQL Server rather than at the Java Connection Pool/ ThreadExecutor. I also heared that MySQL 5.5 has better support for InnoDB locking? Is it true? (I'm still using 5.1.x)